# power bi measure with 2 conditions 2 calculate

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to create a measure which will calculate the Total Project Revenue
while I have 2 different projects. For each project there is a different calculation:
for Hourly project the calculation should be: Income * BillHours
for Retainer project the calculation should be: Income*TotalWorkinghours

I wrote the below DAX:

```
    enter code here : Total project revenue = IF(max(DimProjects[ProjectType])="Hours", 
max(FactWorkingHours[Income])[BillHours],max(FactWorkingHours[Income])* 
[Total Working Hours])
```

the rows are calculated correctly but the total in the table is wrong
what should I fix in DAX so the total of all raw will correct as well.
The total Revenue should be 126,403.33

Thank you in advance
[you can find here the table with the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6rP0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what your measure is doing because, as written here, that is not a valid measure. I pasted it into the [DAX Formatter](https://www.daxformatter.com/), which I would recommend for formatting and pasting here into code blocks, and the measure was invalid. It would also be helpful to post the other measures this measure references, eg. [Bill Hours] and [Income Hours].

That being said, I think I can kind of tell what's going on. Your total is probably wrong because the filter context at the total level is being based of the condition where:

`MAX ( DimProjects[ProjectType] ) = "Retainer"` (or some other value not in your shared snippet)

That is because when you consider the MAX of a string, the higher alphabetical order is considered. Therefore, "Retainer" > "Hours". So at the total level, your table is outputting—more than likely, I can't be certain without more information—the false condition of your measure:

`MAX ( FactWorkingHours[Income] ) * [Total Working Hours])`

There is a better way to handle your intended outcome. IF statements, in the way you are attempting to use it, are rarely used in a calculated measure. You may be better off trying a calculated column without using the MAX functions. Again, I can't give an exact code recommendation without more context. Hope that sends you in the right direction!